# htaccess 301 redirects with email inside url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have following type of url that has been reported by Google as 401

```
http://example.com/products/name/product-name/support@email.com
http://example.com/product-name.php%5C%22
http://example.com/career/%7Bjoblink%7D
```

how do I 301 these urls using htaccess? What I tried is as follow but didnt worked:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^products\/name\/product\-name\/support\@email\.com$ "http\:\/\/www\.exmaple\.com\/products\.php" [R=301,L]
```

does those special characters such as @ requires different approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule with `B` flag in your `/blog/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^2010/01/drying-glass-washing/doug@ 2010/01/drying-glass-washing/ [R=301,L,B,NC]
```

For rest of 2 URLs have these 2 rules in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(product-name.php).+ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(career/)[^\w-] /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: from some reason it does not work and that url is redirected to a page I specified.

Comment: But if it got redirected to `/products.php` then it worked right?

Comment: Nope, I didn't even redirected to /products.php page or any other I specified.

Comment: I think you're a bit confused. Above rule that I suggested **will redirect to `/products.php`** if `support@email.com` is found in URI

Comment: yes, I understand that. This is the actual url that I have blog/2010/01/drying-glass-washing/doug@stream-tek.com and I need it to be 301 redirect to blog/2010/01/drying-glass-washing/

Comment: And where is your .htaccess located? Inside `/blog/` or a level above `/blog/`?

Comment: its located inside website root, so its not inside /blog/

Comment: nope, still does not work. Can you tell me about other two urls I specified in my question. How to redirect them?

Comment: The thing is your question's URL look totally different from your comment's URL. So it is difficult to get a good sense on what you're trying to do here. Do you have `/blog/.htaccess` file also?

Comment: yes, /blog/.htaccess also exist and when I delete it WP url structure does not work so I have to keep that too

Comment: Look at modified answer. Make sure this is your first rule in `/blog/.htaccess` file.

Comment: great, its working now. Thanks a lot for this. Now regarding second and third one, how to redirect them? They are not under /blog/ but regular website page.

Comment: When I add that I get redirected to following urls http://example.com/career%252f  and  http://example.com/product%252dname%252ephp